# How to get CPU precentage usage of a role without using azure diagnostics?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

In the new Windows Azure managament portal it is possible to read information about role's CPU precentage usage. Is it possible to use the same API the portal uses for monitoring within a role instance (eg. worker role)? I know that azure diagnostics can monitor these values for me but portal manages somehow to extract those informations without need to initialise and start diagnostics monitor (without providing diagnostic connection strings).